# Pyspark: Create Dataframe - Boolean fields in Map type are parsed as null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am creating dataframe from a python list as below,

```
_test = [('val1', {'key1': ['A', 'B'], 'key2': ['C'], 'bool_key1': True, 'bool_key2': True}),
           ('val2', {'key1': ['B'], 'key2': ['D'], 'bool_key1': False, 'bool_key2': None})]
df_test = spark.createDataFrame(_test, schema = ["col1","col2"])
df_test.show(truncate=False)
```

but, dataframe resulted has all boolean fields as null!

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|col1|col2                                                     |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|val1|[key1 -> [A, B], bool_key2 ->, key2 -> [C], bool_key1 ->]|
|val2|[key1 -> [B], bool_key2 ->, key2 -> [D], bool_key1 ->]   |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

df_test dataframe schema

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

any help I can create dataframe without changing the python variable structure?

Comment: You need to define the `MapType` within `struct schema`. Additionally, how come you're getting `ArrayType` structure within `col2` ?

Comment: It is already parsed as Map, added schema of resulting dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @wwnde 's answer, there's another way of defining the struct schema (though would personally prefer @wwnde 's answer (fewer lines of code)) -

Defining the `struct` schema -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType(
                    [
                      StructField("col1", StringType()),
                      StructField("col2", StructType([
                                                       StructField("key1", ArrayType(StringType())),
                                                       StructField("key2", ArrayType(StringType())),
                                                       StructField("bool_key1", BooleanType()),
                                                       StructField("bool_key2", BooleanType())
                                                      ]
                                                     )
                                 )
                    ]
                  )
```

Creating the `dataframe` -

```
_test = [
         ('val1', {'key1': ['A', 'B'], 'key2': ['C'], 'bool_key1': True, 'bool_key2': True}),
         ('val2', {'key1': ['B'], 'key2': ['D'], 'bool_key1': False, 'bool_key2': None})
        ]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data=_test, schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
```

**Output**

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- key2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- bool_key1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bool_key2: boolean (nullable = true)
```

If you want to have the `MapType` `key` `value` pairs intact try using below logic -

```
_test = [
         ('val1', {'key1': ['A', 'B'], 'key2': ['C'], 'bool_key1': True, 'bool_key2': True}),
         ('val2', {'key1': ['B'], 'key2': ['D'], 'bool_key1': False, 'bool_key2': None})
        ]

schema = StructType([
                      StructField("col1", StringType()),
                      StructField("col2", (MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
])

spark.createDataFrame(_test, schema=["col1", "col2"]).show(truncate=False)

df_test = spark.createDataFrame(data = _test, schema = schema)
df_test.show(truncate=False)

+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col1|col2                                                               |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|val1|{key1 -> [A, B], bool_key2 -> true, key2 -> [C], bool_key1 -> true}|
|val2|{key1 -> [B], bool_key2 -> null, key2 -> [D], bool_key1 -> false}  |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
df_test.printSchema()

root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the schema and dont define the rows using a tuple. Use a list. try the following code

```
_test1 = [["val1",{"key1": ["A", "B"], "key2": ["C"], "bool_key1": True, "bool_key2": True}],
         ["val1",{"key1": ["A", "B"], "key2": ["C"], "bool_key1": True, "bool_key2": True}],
         ["val2", {"key1": ["B"], "key2": ["D"], "bool_key1": False, "bool_key2": None}]]

df2=spark.createDataFrame(_test1, 'col1 string, col2 struct<key1:array<string>,key2:array<string>,bool_key1:boolean,bool_key1:boolean>')
df2.show(truncate=False)

+----+-------------------------+
|col1|col2                     |
+----+-------------------------+
|val1|{[A, B], [C], true, true}|
|val1|{[A, B], [C], true, true}|
|val2|{[B], [D], false, false} |
+----+-------------------------+

root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- key2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- bool_key1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bool_key1: boolean (nullable = true)
```